# Unix system with windows-style registry

Tags: windows, linux, binwalk

When trying to determine the filesystem of a firmware image using binwalk, I encountered a strange combination.
The binwalk is returning a lot of Unix paths, but some of them contain a typical windows-style registry.

```
3157752       0x302EF8        Unix path: /dev/ffd/DNL
3159348       0x303534        Unix path: /dev/fgs/download
3166204       0x304FFC        Unix path: /dev/rp_if/download
3198300       0x30CD5C        Unix path: /dev/registry/LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/BLAUPUNKT/PROCESS
3201380       0x30D964        Unix path: /dev/registry/LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/BLAUPUNKT/PROCESS/%s
```

Did you see anything like this before?
What could the filesystem/operating system be?

Comment: Unix goes by "everything is a file". Technically this is also true for Windows at the NT native API level - much more so than it lets on - but this means first and foremost that a path can be accessed uniformly through a common root. This is true on Windows (`\ ` -> `\REGISTRY` and `\GLOBAL??\C:`) as well as Unix. My guess is that a driver exists that populates whatever is in there and you can use standard read/write to interact with that data. `/proc` and `/sys` are not much different in that respect. But I didn't see _that_ exact system, no.

Comment: As a side-note, I believe binwalk points out a mere _path_ in this case, not an actual file. I reckon the "file" will only become visible on a running kernel that provides the `/dev/registry` device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to automotive. I had seen something like this in [this](https://github.com/ea/bosch_headunit_root/blob/main/README.md) repository, strings including /dev/registry/LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/BLAUPUNKT are mentioned directly [here](https://github.com/ea/bosch_headunit_root/blob/main/docs/rtos_interaction.md).
Using word "registry" here looks like a coincidence.
[image: Explanation on libOSAL, OS abstraction layer]